# Read and write with Consistency Level Quorum and Retry Policy with DowngradingConsistencyRetryPolicy

Tags: cassandra

I use read write queries with CL of quorum but I have used DowngradingConsistencyRetryPolicy for higher availability. What happens in the below case:

Cluster has 3 nodes and RF is 3. One write query resulted in CL ONE because of retry policy. So the value of the cell is v<sub>0</sub> with timestamp of t<sub>0</sub> at Node<sub>0</sub> and Node<sub>1</sub>. v<sub>1</sub> with timestamp of t<sub>1</sub> at Node<sub>2</sub>. t<sub>1</sub> > t<sub>0</sub>.

What happens when I try to read this cell with a CL of quorum? Do I get stale data or some error. When read repair happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a single data center cluster with a replication factor of 3, and a read consistency level of QUORUM, 2 of the 3 replicas for the given row must respond to fulfill the read request. If the contacted replicas have different versions of the row, the replica with the most recent version will return the requested data. In the background, the third replica is checked for consistency with the first two, and if needed, a read repair is initiated for the out-of-date replicas.

[Read Consistency level examples](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/dml/dmlClientRequestsRead.html)

Read repair also depends on value of read_repair_chance set at columnfamily level. By Default the value is `0.10` which means 10 out of 100 read requset will initiate read repair

Comment: So, there is a chance that I will get stale data if Node0 and Node1 is selected. But background repair will be run and I will get actual data next time I queried it. Also from the link you have posted I understand that read_repair_chance is only used for CL ONE. For QUORUM there is always a read repair phase.

Comment: No in that case also you will get the data with latest timestamp